# how to loop time series data set in python?

Tags: python-3.x

i am new to python, i have time series data that was recorded over a period of 1 year(365 days), the spaces between measurements are not the consistent, sometimes 3s,4s or 7s. below is the sample of data towards the end of the 30th of Apr 2011

[find the data here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoQOG.png)

so i want the code that will add up the time until the sum makes a minute from the start time, so when adding up times and sometimes find that the row that is about to complete a minute make the sum exceed maybe by 2sec (e.g start time=23:40:40 and the row that will complete a minutes is 23:41:42), then leave out that row and average all the data that falls within a minutes (in other words we averaging the data that falls within a minute or less), and the next start time for the next minute will be the row that was left out. i am not sure if i am clear enough.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what difficulties are you experiencing? Do you have a code sample as a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you can iterate through rows by yourself and rows are sorted from least

```
import datetime as dt
first_time = dt.datetime(Y,M,D, h,m,s) # extractfrom first row
delta = dt.timedelta(minutes=1)
next_time = first_time + delta  # first time that does not go in current minute
sums = {}

def key_format(dt_ob: dt.datetime) -> str:
    return f'{dt_ob.year:04}{dt_ob.month:02}{dt_ob.day:02}{dt_ob.hour:02}{dt_ob.minute:02}'
key = key_format(first_time) # format is YYYYMMDDhhmm; seconds not needed cuz they vary inside a minute

for i in rows: # do it however you can, comment answer with where data is stored if you can't
    curent_time = dt.datetime(...) # extract time from i
    if current_time >= next_time: # determine if time is outside minute
        key = key_format(next_time) # change key to next
        next_time += delta # move time to next minute
    sums[key] = sums.get(key, 0) + seconds_to_add_up_in_this_row
    # sums.get(key, 0) returns sums[key] or 0 if key not in sums
```

Comment: PLease find the data : [link] (http://localhost:8888/edit/Mbalie%20/2019/Mbali%202019%20Research%20/Year%202011%20Data/Appended%20data/April/Tim%2CNpts%2CSkylvl_table/table2_Apr)

Comment: Please note that the data that i want to average over a minute is one on the second and third column (Npts and Skylvl), then the column for dates and time should appear as 2011-04-01 00:00:01 in the first row, which will correspond to the first averaged minute.

Comment: I assumed you can extract columns from single row. If that is a problem you should give me insight into row (what data type etc.).  If you can't extract datetime object from first row, than say it like that, it is easily done with RegEx. Also you can ask about any line of my code

Comment: what is line 2 (return f....) of the second paragraph intending to do? And also the last paragraph, i do not get what is it that code does.

Comment: 2nd paragraph, 2nd line is a [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings). `:02` part tells string that comes here that if it is less than 2 characters long fill it with zeros, I'll comment 3rd paragraph